# Use Win32API: unions within structures generate TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, c, winapi, structure, unions

I'd like to import an extern function of Win32API.

The Code from the API (in C) looks like this:

```
typedef struct _BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS {
  union {
    BTH_ADDR ullLong;
    BYTE     rgBytes[6];
  };
} BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS;
```

My C# implementation looks like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 8)]
public struct BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ulong ullLong;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte[] rgBytes;
};
```

The problem is: As soon as I create the struct, it throws me a TypeLoadException, error Code:
System.TypeLoadException: "Could not load type 'BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS' from assembly 'BleLab, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 2 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field."

Do you have any idea to fix this or where the problem is?

Best regards

**Edit:**
Forgot to provide the way of calling:

```
var ba = new Win32API.BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS();
ba.rgBytes = new byte[6];
```

Comment: Are you aware what a C `union` is?

Comment: I tried to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you understand the error, note the following:

1. All members of a C union type have overlapping storage that begins at offset 0, so the offset of member `rgBytes` in your C# struct should use `[FieldOffset(0)]`, not `[FieldOffset(2)]`.
2. The type of the `rgBytes` member in the C union is a fixed array of 6 bytes. In your C# struct it is a `byte[]` array type.  A (normal) array type in C# is a "reference type", which can be thought of as being like a C pointer.  That is, the object just holds a reference (pointer) to a value on the heap.
3. You can create a fixed array using the `fixed` keyword as follows:

   `fixed byte rgBytes[6];`

   Fixed arrays are unsafe code, so the above needs to be declared `unsafe`. It is also declared `public` in your struct, so the full declaration of the `rgBytes` member can be as follows:

   `public unsafe fixed byte rgBytes[6];`

Putting it all together gives the following C# declaration for `BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 8)]
public struct BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ulong ullLong;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public unsafe fixed byte rgBytes[6];
};
```

You can probably leave out the `Size = 8` part.

As per David Heffernan's answer, you are probably better off just using a `ulong`, especially as that will avoid any "unsafe" code.

Comment: This is really the wrong way to solve the problem. If you want to enable the access of the meaningful 6 bytes, do that with access methods. Unsafe code, explicit layout, fixed, all needless complexity for no gain.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan True, as I mentioned in the answer, OP is probably better off avoiding the unsafe code, but it's still reasonable to make corrections to errors in the OP's original attempt to translate the C union members into a C# struct. There are also endianness issues with treating a bluetooth address as a `ulong` value when it is really a sequence of 6 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no point in trying to declare this as a union. It's an unsigned 64 bit type. Just use `ulong` instead of the struct.

If you never need to display the address, then you would need to pick out just the first 6 bytes of that `ulong`. A Bluetooth address is a 48 bit value, hence 6 bytes.

But for your purposes there's nothing to be gained by trying to express that nuance in the type used for interop. Which is why I would recommend working with `ulong` for the interop and picking out the meaningful bytes if necessary as a separate action.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know the possibility to only write `ulong` instead. It now works!